# Twilio click to call

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, twilio

I'm trying to make a page that will allow users to click a button in a browser so they can make a call to a phone number in our office. When I debug the code it all runs fine but when I click the button on the page nothing happens. I don't see any errors in the developer tools either.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-large" runat="server" onclick="callpage_Click" style="margin-left:95px"><i class="icon-phone"></i> Call us!</button>



protected void callpage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account 
            string AccountSid = "************";
            string AuthToken = "************";
            var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);


    // Build the parameters 
    CallOptions options = new CallOptions();
    options.To = "+**********";
    options.From = "+*************";
    options.Url = "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml";
    options.ApplicationSid = "*****************";
    options.Method = "GET";
    options.FallbackMethod = "GET";
    options.StatusCallbackMethod = "GET";
    options.Record = false;

    var call = twilio.InitiateOutboundCall(options);
    Console.WriteLine(call.Sid);
    if (call.RestException == null)
    {
        Response.Write(string.Format("Started call: {0}", call.Sid));
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write(string.Format("Error: {0}", call.RestException.Message));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a call server-side. If you want the call to occur in the browser you need to implement a client-side solution.

We have created a client side phone based on the documentation provided here:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/twilio-client-browser-soft-phone

The only server-side portion of the solution should be when you create the token that you need to make the call in the browser. Here is some sample code:

```
public string TwilioToken {
    get {
        var capability = new TwilioCapability("TwilioSid", "TwilioToken");
        capability.AllowClientOutgoing("TwilioApplicationIdCreatedOnTheirSite");
        return capability.GenerateToken();
    }
}
```

This token is referred to as the Twilio Capability Token in their documentation and was a little confusing to me at first.

This is sample code I pulled from our implementation. It uses jQuery so you will need to include that if you want to use this in your site.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.1/twilio.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Twilio.Device.setup("<%=TwilioToken%>");

        Twilio.Device.connect(function (conn) {
            $("#hangup").show();
            $("#call").hide();
        });

    });

    function call(param1, param2) {
        params = { "Param1": param1, "Param2": param2 };
        connection = Twilio.Device.connect(params);
    }

    function hangup() {
        Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
        $("#hangup").hide();
        $("#call").show();
    }
</script>

<a id="call" href="javascript:call('a', 'b');">Call</a>
<a id="hangup" href="javascript:hangup();">Hangup</a>
```

Comment: The code I specified above needs to go in the code behind. The rest of the code that you need is JavaScript. I will add some of the JavaScript code that we use.